# How can I configure hibernate logging in a EAP/EAR/"per-deployment" configuration?

Tags: hibernate, jboss, ear

I have an EAP (7.4.7) environment.

In my EAR I using "per-deployment" logging, so I have META-INF/logging.properties.
In general it works.

I also want control hibernate logging e.g: `org.hibernate.SQL` -> DEBUG in the logging.properties.

Is this possible? I can't get it work and I don't find any useful examples.

Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately that cannot currently be done. All global modules, of which Hibernate is, always use the server level log context. There is https://issues.redhat.com/browse/LOGMGR-264 which has some links to WildFly JIRA's too.

Comment: Thank you James. OK
During development, I will then turn on the logging with jboss-cli.bat and
/subsystem=logging/logger=org.hibernate.SQL:add(level=DEBUG,handlers=[FILE],use-parent-handlers=false)
It works

Comment: That should work!